# Anyone vs everyone

Tags: word-choice

Can someone help explain if "anyone" or "everyone" should be used in the following sentence?

> We enable ____ to do anything.

Though English is my second language, I've been speaking and writing it for many years and feel that "anyone" is the correct word to use here, though my colleagues feel more strongly for "everyone". However, I can't explain *why* I disagree exactly.

Comment: If it's a firm offering some kind of service, I agree that _anyone_ is better. They can help any person who asks for their services, but they can't expect to help everyone in the town.

Comment: @KateBunting - also, people who make up slogans for organisations love repetition, so _We enable **any**one to do **any**thing_ seems preferable. Given that they aren't meant to be taken literally (they can't, I am fairly sure, enable my blind cousin to see, or enable me to fly), I think _We enable **every**one to do **every**thing_ isn't all that crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct.

"*[Anyone](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anyone)*" is '*any person at all*', and "*[everyone](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/everyone)*" is '*every person*'.
A good way to tell them apart is to think about the difference between "*does anyone have the right time?*" and "*does everyone have the right time?*" (or, to get a sense of the difference between 'any' and 'every', "*we enable everyone to do **any**thing*" and "*we enable everyone to do **every**thing*").

So choosing which one is a better fit depends on what you want the phrase to emphasize. What is this slogan/motto for, what is the context? Do you focus on specific individuals, or on helping large(r) groups of people?

(It's quite a claim, in either case!)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the example. Just to be sure: is it then valid to write *We enable everyone to do anything*? For context, the sentence is related to enabling people to move anything and not just generically to anything. I was just generalising a bit :D

Comment: @Lasse "*We enable everyone to move anything*" addresses people as a whole, whereas "*We enable anyone to move anything*" focuses on an individual. But I think the latter has a slightly "needy" vibe, as if begging for clientele ("*is there anyone who wants this?*"). I think the first is the more appropriate one, yes. (By the way, it's usually better to include as much information as you can in your question, so that the answers you get are as explicit as possible. Context is very important.)

Comment: And also consider using "you"; "we enable you ..".

Comment: Good point. Thanks for explaining

Comment: (@Lasse You can also wait a while with accepting an answer, so that others are more inclined to answer, as well, and you'll get a broader perspective :)

Comment: A service that's used by nearly everyone (maybe in a certain geographical area) might say "we enable everyone to..." or "we feed/help/serve everyone..." etc. For instance Google or Transport for London. But most firms couldn't claim that.